# Guidance on Execution Algo Passive order placer?

Tags: fx, algorithmic-trading, market-microstructure, market-making, order-execution

Could someone help with any relevant literature about building an Execution Algo and things to consider and keep in mind for optimal passive order placements? There are basic algos like TWAP/VWAP/POV etc, but how does one gain edge on the micro structure level? does it also involve understanding the microstructure better?